# Markers not inline with error bars

Tags: plotting

The ErrorListPlot function in the ErrorBarPlots package displays markers left of the error bars. What is and how to plot the actually correct position?

Example Code:

```
ErrorListPlot[{{3, 1}}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using? As of Version 12, ErrorListPlot has been superseded by ListPlot.

Comment: I remember this being a problem, but don't see it anymore in 12.1. Btw ErrorBarPlots seems deprecated in favour of `ListPlot[{Around[3,1]}]`.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Mathematica are you using? I think older versions didn't quite place plot markers at the locations of the points.

For error bars, as of version 12, use Around instead of the obsolete ErrorListPlot. E.g., from the Around documentation:

```
ListPlot[{Around[1, .1], Around[2, .2], Around[3, .3]}]
```